# Next button to change slide in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var TIMEOUT = 6000;


var interval = setInterval(handleNext, TIMEOUT);

function handleNext() {

    var $radios = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]');
    var $activeRadio = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]:checked');

    var currentIndex = $activeRadio.index();
    var radiosLength = $radios.length;

    $radios
        .attr('checked', false);


    if (currentIndex >= radiosLength - 1) {

        $radios
            .first()
            .attr('checked', true);

    } else {

        $activeRadio
            .next('input[class*="slide-radio"]')
            .attr('checked', true);

    }

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


/* Navigation */

.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-left {
    margin-left: -33px;
}

.navigation-left a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333745;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 107px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.navigation-left a:hover,
.navigation-left a:focus {
    border-color: rgb(234, 46, 73);
    background-color: rgba(44, 45, 47, 0);
}

.navigation-center {
    margin-right: 85px;
}

.navigation-right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.login-btn {
    background-color: #b8b8b9;
    width: 97px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    color: #333745;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 20px;
    transition: all .2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.login-btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.06);
}


/* Slider wrapper*/

.css-slider-wrapper {
    display: block;
    background: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}


/* Slider */

.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
    transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}


/* Slides Background Color */

.slide-1 {
    background: #fbad99;
    left: 0;
}

.slide-2 {
    background: #a9785c;
    left: 100%
}

.slide-3 {
    background: #9ea6b3;
    left: 200%
}

.slide-4 {
    background: #b1a494;
    left: 300%;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.slider-content {
    width: 635px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}


/* Slider Inner Slide Effect */

.slider h2 {
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.2;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
    transform: translateX(500px);
    margin-top: 0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.slider h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.349);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
    transform: translateX(500px);
}

.slider>img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
    transform: translateX(500px);
}

.slide-1>img {
    right: 0;
}

.buy-now-btn {
    background-color: #ea2e49;
    width: 130px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: none;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 35px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.buy-now-btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px -17px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}

.slider .buy-now-btn:focus,
.navigation .login-btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}


/* Animations */

.slider h2 {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
    transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.slider h4 {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
    transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.4s;
    /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 1.4s;
}

.slider>img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
    transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.2s;
    /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}


/* Number Pagination */

.number-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 100px;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.number-pagination span {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ea2e49;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.number-pagination span:after {
    content: "/4";
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}


/* Slider Pagger */

.slider-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 575px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider-pagination label {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* Slider Pagger Event */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider-pagination .page1,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slider-pagination .page2,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slider-pagination .page3,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slider-pagination .page4 {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 2px solid #ea2e49;
    background: transparent;
}


/* Slider Slide Effect */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slide-radio2:checked~.slider {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-radio3:checked~.slider {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.slide-radio4:checked~.slider {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
    transform: translateX(-300%);
}

.slide-radio1:checked~.slide-1 h2,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide-2 h2,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide-3 h2,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide-4 h2,
.slide-radio1:checked~.slide-1 h4,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide-2 h4,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide-3 h4,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide-4 h4,
.slide-radio1:checked~.slide-1>img,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide-2>img,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide-3>img,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide-4>img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1
}


/* Responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .slider h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .slider h4 {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .slider-content {
        padding: 0 2%
    }
    .number-pagination {
        right: 2%;
    }
    .slider-pagination {
        left: 2%;
    }
    .slider .buy-now-btn {
        padding: 0 15px;
        width: 90px;
        height: 42px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0 0 100px 0;
    }
    .slider .buy-now-btn:after {
        top: 15px;
    }
    .slider>img {
        right: 2%;
    }
    .slide-1>img {
        right: -110px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Slider</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->


    <!-- Slider Wrapper -->
    <div class="css-slider-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" id="slider_4">

        <!-- Slider Pagination -->
        <div class="slider-pagination">
            <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
            <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
            <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
            <label for="slider_4" class="page4"></label>
        </div>

        <!-- Slider #1 -->
        <div class="slider slide-1" id="tab1">
            <img src="images/model-1.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <h4>New Product</h4>
                <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
                <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="number-pagination">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slider #2 -->
        <div class="slider slide-2" id="tab2">
            <img src="images/model-2.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <h4>New Product</h4>
                <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
                <button type="button" class="btn" name="button" onclick="prev()">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="number-pagination">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slider #3 -->
        <div class="slider slide-3" id="tab3">
            <img src="images/model-3.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <h4>New Product</h4>
                <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
                <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="number-pagination">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slider #4 -->
        <div class="slider slide-4" id="tab4">
            <img src="images/model-4.png" alt="">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <h4>New Product</h4>
                <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
                <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="number-pagination">
                <span>4</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hi,

I created a small html snippet of slideshow .I created this code using CSS and Java script .I need to know the button I created ,when we click it should move to another next slides and previous slides same as input buttons. Can it be done only using CSS or need to use JavaScript . I am newbie to JavaScript. Answer to this would be helpful .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use similar function to `next()` and use `.prev` instead of `.next`, which will make sure it will select previous sibling.

```js
var TIMEOUT = 6000;


var interval = setInterval(handleNext, TIMEOUT);

function handleNext() {

  var $radios = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]');
  var $activeRadio = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]:checked');

  var currentIndex = $activeRadio.index();
  var radiosLength = $radios.length;

  $radios
    .attr('checked', false);


  if (currentIndex >= radiosLength - 1) {

    $radios
      .first()
      .attr('checked', true);

  } else {

    $activeRadio
      .next('input[class*="slide-radio"]')
      .attr('checked', true);

  }

}

function next() {
  clearInterval(interval); //To make sure it doesn't interfere when slide is manually changed
  handleNext();
  interval = setInterval(handleNext, TIMEOUT); //Again Set the interval
}

function prev() {
  clearInterval(interval); //To make sure it doesn't interfere when slide is manually changed
  var $radios = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]');
  var $activeRadio = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]:checked');

  var currentIndex = $activeRadio.index();
  var radiosLength = $radios.length;

  $radios
    .attr('checked', false);


  if (currentIndex >= radiosLength - 1) {

    $radios
      .first()
      .attr('checked', true);

  } else {

    $activeRadio
      .prev('input[class*="slide-radio"]')
      .attr('checked', true);

  }
  interval = setInterval(handleNext, TIMEOUT); //Again Set the interval
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


/* Navigation */

.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation-left {
  margin-left: -33px;
}

.navigation-left a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333745;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 107px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.navigation-left a:hover,
.navigation-left a:focus {
  border-color: rgb(234, 46, 73);
  background-color: rgba(44, 45, 47, 0);
}

.navigation-center {
  margin-right: 85px;
}

.navigation-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.login-btn {
  background-color: #b8b8b9;
  width: 97px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  color: #333745;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: all .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}


/* Slider wrapper*/

.css-slider-wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Slider */

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* Slides Background Color */

.slide-1 {
  background: #fbad99;
  left: 0;
}

.slide-2 {
  background: #a9785c;
  left: 100%
}

.slide-3 {
  background: #9ea6b3;
  left: 200%
}

.slide-4 {
  background: #b1a494;
  left: 300%;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.slider-content {
  width: 635px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}


/* Slider Inner Slide Effect */

.slider h2 {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  transform: translateX(500px);
  margin-top: 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.slider h4 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.349);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.2;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  transform: translateX(500px);
}

.slider>img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  transform: translateX(500px);
}

.slide-1>img {
  right: 0;
}

.buy-now-btn {
  background-color: #ea2e49;
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.buy-now-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px -17px rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}

.slider .buy-now-btn:focus,
.navigation .login-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Animations */

.slider h2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
  transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.slider h4 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
  transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1.4s;
}

.slider>img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
  transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1.2s;
}


/* Number Pagination */

.number-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 100px;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.number-pagination span {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ea2e49;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.number-pagination span:after {
  content: "/4";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Slider Pagger */

.slider-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 575px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-pagination label {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Slider Pagger Event */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider-pagination .page1,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slider-pagination .page2,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slider-pagination .page3,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slider-pagination .page4 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #ea2e49;
  background: transparent;
}


/* Slider Slide Effect */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slide-radio2:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-radio3:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.slide-radio4:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}

.slide-radio1:checked~.slide-1 h2,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide-2 h2,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide-3 h2,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide-4 h2,
.slide-radio1:checked~.slide-1 h4,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide-2 h4,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide-3 h4,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide-4 h4,
.slide-radio1:checked~.slide-1>img,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide-2>img,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide-3>img,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide-4>img {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1
}


/* Responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .slider h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .slider-content {
    padding: 0 2%
  }
  .number-pagination {
    right: 2%;
  }
  .slider-pagination {
    left: 2%;
  }
  .slider .buy-now-btn {
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 0 100px 0;
  }
  .slider .buy-now-btn:after {
    top: 15px;
  }
  .slider>img {
    right: 2%;
  }
  .slide-1>img {
    right: -110px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Slider</title>

  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->


  <!-- Slider Wrapper -->
  <div class="css-slider-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" id="slider_4">

    <!-- Slider Pagination -->
    <div class="slider-pagination">
      <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
      <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
      <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
      <label for="slider_4" class="page4"></label>
    </div>

    <!-- Slider #1 -->
    <div class="slider slide-1" id="tab1">
      <img src="images/model-1.png" alt="">
      <div class="slider-content">
        <h4>New Product</h4>
        <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
        <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
      </div>
      <div class="number-pagination">
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slider #2 -->
    <div class="slider slide-2" id="tab2">
      <img src="images/model-2.png" alt="">
      <div class="slider-content">
        <h4>New Product</h4>
        <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="button" onclick="prev()">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
      </div>
      <div class="number-pagination">
        <span>2</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slider #3 -->
    <div class="slider slide-3" id="tab3">
      <img src="images/model-3.png" alt="">
      <div class="slider-content">
        <h4>New Product</h4>
        <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="button" onclick="prev()">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
      </div>
      <div class="number-pagination">
        <span>3</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slider #4 -->
    <div class="slider slide-4" id="tab4">
      <img src="images/model-4.png" alt="">
      <div class="slider-content">
        <h4>New Product</h4>
        <h2>Denim Longline T-Shirt Dress With Split</h2>
        <button type="button" class="buy-now-btn" name="button" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
      </div>
      <div class="number-pagination">
        <span>4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello need small help ,can we make here swipe left right to change slides. If yes using css or Javascript?

Comment: @Tharun Yes you can, but you will need an external JavaScript library. I would suggest `swiper.js`. Check [here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api)

Comment: Hello  I tried in different way , I am adding that in code please check once